# Good practice for doing a Django media backup

Tags: python, django, backup, media

Is there any good practice for doing a **Django media backup**?

I know there are tools like https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup but I can't make it work with `management.call_command("mediabackup")` when using options, I want to specify the generated `tar` file name, so I can upload it to a remote storage.

*I actually opened an issue about that https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup/issues/278*

So, I'm looking for a way of doing my own backup. It looks like making a compressed version of the `media` folder is just what's necessary, but I'm not sure (mediarestore seems to to some stuff on the background) so I'm looking for good practices or example.